# Can you pass a None argument when docstring requires a string?

Tags: python, pycharm, lint, docstring

Ok, this question has probably been answered somewhere but my Google-fu hasn't found the right combination of keywords yet.

I have a function that accepts a string, but when I pass None, Pycharm's inspection is flagging a type error. Is this an error in the linter? Does None count as a string? I know I can call the function with an empty string, but I think I should be able to use None as well.

```
def my_func(some_str):
""" does something
Arguments:
some_str (str): a string
"""
    # do something

...

my_func(None)  <-- throws Expected type 'str', got 'None' instead
```

Comment: just pass empty string (`""`) instead of None

Comment: No because when performing an action on a string, it is only able to perform that operation on something which is of the type `str` however the value of `None` is a `NoneType`, which is its own individual type, meaning that `None` can not be used in place of a `str`, however you could use empty quotes, `""` which would pass in a string with no content

Comment: `None` is not a string. `None` is `None`, a string is a `str`. PyCharm itself won't "throw" anything, neither will Python itself. Only some type check in the function itself might raise an actual error. So I'm unclear what you're asking… if the function rejects `None` as a valid argument, then the question is answering itself, no?

Comment: this seems like odd behaviour from pycharm to me. because python isn't strongly typed there is never any reason you can't pass a different type to the function, the function should handle appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a dissenting opinion, Python is not strongly typed so for pycharm's linter to highlight that as an error seems a little odd to me.

Of course there are many functions which legitimately need a string, but I'm sure i saw somewhere that 'good practice' for that was a function that looked more like this:

```
def myfunct(s):
    try:
        s = str(s)
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError('message explaining function usage')
    # actual function
```

This works with anything that can be coerced into a string, which seems more sensible than requiring literally a string.

Am I nuts?

Comment: I think the reason PyCharm is complaining about it, is because of the docstring that the code contains. I haven't used docstrings in Pycharm, so I don't know for sure, but that's the only reason I can think of.

Comment: I like this as it follows python's ask for forgiveness model. Also glad to see there are differences of opinion - it's not a straightforward question.

Answer (score 4):

First to answer your question `None` is not a `str` It is the sole value of `type.Nonetype` it is a python Built in Contstant. Read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html).
And there are many ways to get around/handle possible `None` input

**1. To get around it, not going to handle None:**

is expecting `str` so of course, it throws an error. just pass in `""` instead. but in this case calling `my_func(None)` would still give you an error.

```
my_func("")
```

**2. To Handle possible `None` input:**

if you want to handle `None` as one of possible input parameter then set your parameter  to **optional parameter** with `*` that way you can input `None` and not get an error

```
def my_func(*some_str):
```

**OR**

**Default your input to `None`** if the value user pass in is not `None` then you know user pass in something else: This allows you do to `my_func(None)` and not get an error

```
def my_func(some_str = None):
  if some_str:
    #do something
```

Note: this also allows you treat `None` and `''` equally (thanks to Stael for pointing out)

Comment: if you do `if some_str:` then it will treat `None` and `''` equally, which is closer to what the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

`None` does not count as a string. `None` is the sole member of the class `NoneType`.

To do what you want, arrange for your function to accept an optional string argument.

```
def my_func(some_str: str = None):
```

Then don't pass it `None`, pass it nothing:

```
a = my_func()
```

Comment: In the actual code, there are more positional args after the str arg, so turning it into a kwarg is not an option, unfortunately. I don't want to make changes to the interface if I can avoid it.

Comment: Mmm, that wasn't clear from your question. In that case I would simply forget about the type hint.

Comment: Sorry, guess I simplified it too much :-)

Comment: If you really have to have the type hint because it's an inflexible project standard or something, then do: `from typing import Union` followed by `def my_func(some_str: Union[str,None]):` That expresses what you want and will shut PyCharm's linter up.